# Unable to unmount /proc

Tags: unmount

I started customizing live ubuntu cd. I followed all the steps in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd) but i am not able to unmount the `/proc`. Please look @ the below error.. The error says some process where running but i am not able to figure out the process.. Can anyone help ?

### Error

```
root@karthick:/# umount /proc/
umount: /proc: device is busy.
(In some cases useful info about processes that use
the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

Comment: Could you escape your chroot and run `sudo lsof -n ~/livecd/custom` on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably trying to do this in a `root` environment and not the `chroot` environment.

See the difference between

```
/home/rinzwind$ sudo su
/home/rinzwind# umount /proc
umount: /proc: device is busy.
    (In some cases useful info about processes that use
     the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
root@discworld:/home/rinzwind# exit
```

and

```
rinzwind@discworld:~$ sudo chroot ~/livecd/custom
bash-4.2# umount /proc
```

The 1st tries to umount /proc for the system you are using and of course fails. The 2nd one is done on the chrooted environment and works.

Looking at your prompt `root@karthick`: this should be a bash prompt.